# Can we create an alert from 2 different data sources in grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-api, grafana-alerts

Can we create an alert in Grafana from 2 graphs(2 data sources) and compare the values in those graphs.

For eg: I have a parameter in 1 data source, 1 parameter in another data source, I created a graph for both of them. Can I create an alert to compare these two queries(A and B) that belong to 2 different data sources like ((A-B)=0)

Answer (score 2):

**Q:** Can we create an alert in Grafana from 2 graphs(2 data sources)?

**A:** Depends. Up till Grafana version 5 you can only create alert for datasources provided by Grafana's core. e.g. `Influxdb`, `Cloudwatch`.

That is, you can't create alert for custom data sources yet.

**Q:** Can I compare the values from the 2 data sources? E.g. ((A-b)=0)

**A:** Looking at the UI for alert, I think the functionality is pretty limited at the moment. You can't do mathematical operation between queries yet. So `((A-b)=0)` is not possible.

**Q:** Is there alternative?

**A:** Probably the easiest way out for you is to write your own application for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in the latest version of Grafana
[image: Multiple data sources]